# C Check when 2D-Int array is full

Tags: c, arrays, microcontroller

I want check in my 2 Dimensional array when it is full.
But its not working because I'm not sure how to know which one is full value_array[x][when this is full].

I can do static short array_status1 =0; static short array_status2 =0; 
static short array_status3 =0; static short array_status4 =0; and increment it when I use one of the dms = 1,2,3,4 . But is there a other way ?

My programm is not working because of if(array_status > array_length) . If my function is called not just for one dms it writes values 10 time, for example 5 values dms =1 and 5 values dms=2

I programming in C in a microcontroller.

```
#define array_length 10

static int value_array[4][array_length];

static short array_status =0;


int average_value(int value,short dms)
{
    int average,i =0;

    if(array_status > array_length)
    { 
        //average_value
    array_status=0;  
        for(i =0 ; i < array_length ; i++)
     {
        average += value_array[dms][i];
     }
     average = average / array_length;  
  }
    else 
        average =0;

    value_array[dms][array_status] = value;
    array_status++;

    return average;
}
```

Comment: Not really, you  have to keep track of what index you're at. So you either have to pass it in or store it somewhere

Comment: I agree with Scotty Bauer.  You're hard-coding the size of the 2D array, so knowing if you've reached the last element should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the indices in an array.

```
#define array_length 10
#define array_dim    4

static int value_array[array_dim][array_length];

static short array_status[array_dim] = {0};

int average_value(int value, short dms)
{
    int average, i = 0;

    if(array_status[dms] > array_length)
    {
        //average_value
        array_status[dms] = 0;  
        for(i = 0 ; i < array_length ; i++)
        {
            average += value_array[dms][i];
        }
        average = average / array_length;  
    }
    else 
        average = 0;

    value_array[dms][array_status[dms]] = value;
    array_status[dms]++;

    return average;
}
```